# Out Of Memory issues with lot of org/glassfish/grizzly/memory/HeapMemoryManager$TrimmableHeapBuffer objects

Tags: java, memory, glassfish, out-of-memory

Hello we are facing Out Of Memory issues on Glassfish 4 server.
Heap Analysis shows that about 75-80% of the heap is filled up by

org/glassfish/grizzly/memory/HeapMemoryManager$TrimmableHeapBuffer !

Please refer to link below for the screenshot of the heap analysis.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJEQV.png

As you can see in the image, the byte array contains only sequence of four byte 18, 52, 0, 0. Except that last four bytes from 65532 to 65535 are as follows
6, 31, -6, 0

I am not able to figure out what all this is about.

Any pointers to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For future reference, this issue was filed as [GRIZZLY-1703](https://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-1703)